# Send email with django + gunicorn + nginx get timeout

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, sendmail, amazon-ses

I'm trying to deploy a Django project in AWS with gunicorn + nginx but I'm getting a timeout error. My email backend uses AWS SES with SMTP authentication.
The first 2 emails are sent normally, after these I'm getting this error.
The account is already an unblocked restriction for sending an email.

Local django development server works fine, it sends emails normally. In local virtual machine with same EC2 specs sends emails normally.

Running in django shell I'm getting this log at third email sent:

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 5, in sendE
  File "/home/ubuntu/myproj/share/forms.py", line 23, in share_email
    email_message.send()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproj-rqmaW6Yv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 291, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproj-rqmaW6Yv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 103, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproj-rqmaW6Yv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 63, in open
    self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
    self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 727, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 716, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```
Any idea?
````

Answer (score 1):

Ok after testing a lot, I Found EC2 instances have a restriction over default smtp port connection. Change the port from 25 to 587 and it works perfectly.

More info: https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/smtp-connectivity-timeout-issues-ses/